# @client.event not triggered (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
from keepawake import keepawake
import os
import requests
import discord
from discord import Webhook, RequestsWebhookAdapter, File
import time
from discord.ext import commands

webhook = Webhook.partial(863030277597036574,os.environ['WTOKEN'],\
 adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")





votecount = 0
vote = None

@client.command()

async def votekick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason="inconnue"):
 emojis = ['✅', '❌']
 adminBug = client.get_channel(863158034292801577)
 message = await ctx.send("voulez vous kick "+str(member)[:-5]+"?" f"                        raison du vote: {reason}")
 
 for emoji in emojis:
     await message.add_reaction(emoji)
 
 
 @client.event   
 async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    emoji = reaction.emoji
    if user.bot:
        return
    if emoji == "":
        fixed_channel = client.get_channel(863158034292801577)
        await fixed_channel.send("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    elif emoji == "✅":
        vote = True
    elif emoji == "❌":
        vote = False
    else:
     return
```

---

```
@client.event  
async def kick(ctx):
   print(vote)
   if vote == True :  
     if reason == None: 
       reason = "raison inconnue"
     message = f"Tu a été banni(e) de {ctx.guild.name} pour {reason}"
     await member.send(message)
     await member.kick(reason=reason)
     await ctx.send(f"{member} a été éjecté du serveur!")
   else:
     await ctx.send(f"{member} ne sera pas kick.")
```

I'm trying to make a discord bot to ban or kick peoples by voting but the second part of the code is not doing anything (like printing "vote") but the first part is working.
I don't know much things about discord.py so I don't know how to make the second part execute by itself after the first part(on_reaction_add) finished running.

Comment: `kick` isn't an event, replace `@client.event` with `@client.command()`

Comment: But I don't want it to run after i make a command, I want it to run after "on_reaction_add" finished running.

Answer (score 0):

the decorator @client.event is used for things like on_startup, which triggers the function every time the bot is started, or on_message which triggers the function every time a message is sent to any guild the bot is in.

What you want is to replace the line

> `@client.event` with `@client.command()` - like MrSpaar says

This means that the function will be triggered every time someone sends the message `!kick @{member}`

Comment: But I want it to be executed after "on_reaction_add" finish running.

Comment: Thank you, I finnaly resolved the issue after founding how to execute the last part (await kick(ctx)

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly resolved the issue after founding how to execute the last part ( await kick(ctx) )